# How to pass port no from hosts.cfg file to services.cfg file in nagios

Tags: nagios

I have hostgroups.cfg file in which i have different hosts with different port no. I want to pass port no for every host to services.cfg file where i have put check_http command.

As my different hosts have different http processes with different port no, so I want to pass port no directly from hosts.cfg file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom object variables

You declare a variable in your host definition starting with an underscore (e.g._http_port1 81)  and reference it in your service/command/contact/etc.  with $_HOSTHTTP_PORT1. Note THE _HOST prefix and the fact that the var has its leading _ stripped off and was capitalized.

You can read more 
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/customobjectvars.html